# Wii Guitar Input in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, guitar, wii

So I got the crazy idea of making my own PC version of Rock Band / Guitar Hero in Unity. To do so, I need to be able to configure the InputManager in order to detect every button.

Through a little trial and error, I've been able to detect input for the color keys as well as the plus and minus buttons. I can't however for the life of me figure out how to get any input from the strum bar or the D-PAD.

I've been trying different combinations of joystick buttons, input types and input axis.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ever anyone else runs into this problem, I figured it out.

The correct InputManager configuration for the Strum Bar on a Harmonix Nintendo Wii Rock Band Guitar is joystick button 5, snap: true, Type: Joystick Axis, Axis: 6th Axis (Joysticks).

If this does not work on your guitar, open up the back. The correct button number is written on the chip where the wiring connects.